# How to configure/define file upload in POST req in Stoplight Studio - for OpenAPI documentation

Tags: openapi, stoplight

[Please bear with me, I'm completely new to APIs, OpenAPI and Stoplight Studio.]

**BACKGROUND FOR THE QUESTION**

I am using Stoplight Studio to implement OpenAPI documentation for a POST request, which involves a file upload.

This is what my FormData looks like:

```
body:{"displayName":"exampleFileCSV","fields":[/*<<content from my fileupload>>*/]}
uploadFile: (binary)
```

This is what my Postman POST request looks like:

[image: Postman POST request I am using]

**QUESTION:**

I'm not able to figure out how to reproduce the same request in Stoplight Studio to document the API in OpenAPI. I need to configure the post request with the formData:{body, fileUpload}:

[image: Stoplight Studio]

If that's not possible, I would like to know how it is implemented in swagger.json alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though there is no way in stoplight studio to implement this, there is a SIMPLE SOLUTION to code it in swagger.json file.

```
      schema:
    type: string
    format: binary
```

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/

You can define a property under content as string in stoplight studio and make the change of adding the 'format: binary' in swagger.json code. Stoplight studio will respect the change without overriding it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to click in the "string" type and select in the "Format" field the "binary" type.

[image]